# RegEx to exclude an exact multi-word match

Tags: regex

I need a RegEx to exclude a case insensitive exact match (entire string).  If the entire string is "United States" (case insensitive) then I need to reject the string.  If only part of the string contains "United States" (case insensitive) then it is fine.

I also need a minimum length of 6 characters for the string, if it is less than six it needs to reject the string.

I am having trouble with this because of the space between the words, and because I need to only exclude an exact match of this string and not a partial match.

This is for vBulletin and I am allowed only a single line regex for this form.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your requirements are still a bit vague, but try

```
^(?i)(?!United States$).{6,}$
```

See it [here on Regexr](http://regexr.com?31rod)

`^` Anchor to the start of the string

`$` Anchor to the end of the string

`(?i)` inline option, making the regex match case insensitive

`(?!United States$)` negative lookahead, make the whole expression fail, if the string is from the start to the end only "United States"

`.{6,}` matches 6 or more characters

Answer (score 0):

Why regex?

I'd do (in perl):

```
reject() if (uc($str) eq 'UNITED STATES' or length($str) < 6);
```